# On my Note 4, even when I set the lock screen to fingerprint, if I turn it off and then on, I can unlock it by swiping. Please advise

Tags: lock-screens, samsung-galaxy-note-4

I set the unlocking to fingerprint. I set 3 fingerprints. I activate them. Then I can unlock my phone by swiping. What is the use?

Comment: Posting this as a comment as it most likely is not a full answer but check in your security setting under "Smart Lock" and ensure it is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Often there is a settings which sets a Timout for a locked phone. By default I think it is set to 5 seconds. That means, that when you turn your screen off your phone waits 5 seconds before activating the lockscreen security. Try searching the settings for this timeout setting.

Answer (score 1):

go to settings- security- trusted agents-and off the google lock

Comment: Could you elaborate as to the applicable Android version for these steps? Also, your terminology is a bit confusing. Please clarify.

Answer (score -1):

settings》lock screen》secured lock time》instant ....GLHF

Comment: Does this work on a Note 4?

Answer (score -1):

Go to settings > Security > Trusted agents-and turn off the Google lock